# foam roller vs brush for fiberglass door

Tags: doors, paint

painting a fiberglass door with semi-gloss latex.  Looking for that smooth glossy finish (yes I know spray would be optimum).  Would it be best to use a foam roller or a brush?
thanks

Comment: You have to play with it and see what results you can get with that paint, those rollers, and various levels of dilution with the paint.   It also helps to lay the door flat so it is drying horizontal not vertical.  You can also try a technique called ["roll and tip"](https://www.google.com/search?q=roll+and+tip+painting&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari).  See also oil paints and techniques found under "$50 Rustoleum paint job".  It's all in the technique.  Also, using gloss paint helps for that glossy look and for cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

Use a smooth foam roller, maybe sand and second coat, then buff. But yes spray would be better.